# R: plotting a raster image inside screen() is not working

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am trying to plot a `rasterLayer` object on a plot composed of two figures using `screen`

First - a working case scenario when we only have one image:

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
rst <- raster(f)

plot(rst)
points(180000, 332000, col="red", pch=19)
```

Everything looks fine and the image looks like this:

[image: image1]

However when I split the screen into two and try to plot the same figure using only half of the plotting region I get the following:

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
rst <- raster(f)
class(rst)

figs <- rbind(c(0, 0.5, 0, 1), # Screen1
              c(0.5, 1, 0, 1)  # Screen2
              )
screenIDs <- split.screen(figs)

screen(screenIDs[1])
plot(rst)
points(180000, 332000, col="red", pch=19)
```

[image: image2]

It seems like the main image of the raster shape is being drawn correctly. However for some reason it then captures the entire plotting region and adds a boundary lines on it. After that subsequent calls to the plot (like `points`) add points on the whole figure rather than staying in the first half of it.

Any ideas how to solve or bypass this are most appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about the `split.screen` functionality but does using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` provide an alternative option?

Comment: @timfaber par(mfrow=c(1,2)) does work. But unfortunately I have a complicated page layout (two halves here are just for reproducible example) and must use `screen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `layout` instead of `split.screen`.  Demonstrated here, as in your example, with a simple layout of just 1 row of two equal-sized panels.  For how to get more complex layouts, have a look at `?layout`

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(rst)
points(180000, 332000, col="red", pch=19)

plot(1:10,1:10) # a dummy plot to put in the right hand panel
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Thank you for taking time to respond. I know layout, but I would really want to use screen for this. Right now investigating a different method for plotting raster using `image()` which seems to work better with screen, but cannot get the resolution right...